# Fabric-ca-server is not able to initialize postgres database after restart

Tags: postgresql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

can someone please help me with this I'm stuck with this error on the production network:

I have to restart my fabric-ca-server and when I have started it I got the following error from fabric ca server, here it is not able to initialize Postgres database:

```
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Initializing DB
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Initializing 'postgres' database at 'host=postgres.example.com port=5432 user=** password=** dbname=fabriccaserver sslmode=verify-full'
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Using postgres database, connecting to database...
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Database Name: fabriccaserver
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=postgres.example.com port=5432 user=** password=** dbname=fabriccaserver sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/root.crt sslcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.crt sslkey=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.key
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'fabriccaserver'
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=postgres.example.com port=5432 user=** password=** dbname=postgres sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/root.crt sslcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.crt sslkey=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.key
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'postgres'
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [DEBUG] Connecting to PostgreSQL server, using connection string: host=postgres.example.com port=5432 user=** password=** dbname=template1 sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/root.crt sslcert=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.crt sslkey=/tmp/postgresCerts/server.key
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [WARNING] Failed to connect to database 'template1'
2020/12/22 12:35:07 [ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to connect to Postgres database. Postgres requires connecting to a specific database, the following databases were tried: [fabriccaserver postgres template1]. Please create one of these database before continuing
```

Comment: How are you running things?  Via Docker?  Is the the database actually running?

Comment: Yes, the postgres is running inside a docker container. The database is running fine and is ready to accept connections.

Comment: It runs fine when we use ssl-mode=disable but when we try with other ssl modes fabric-ca is not able to initialize postgres DB. We have previously used verify-full and it was working fine before we have restarted the fabric-ca container.

Comment: Perhaps something is changing with the certificates the CA is accessing to communicate with Postgres?